# java security restrict access to jar or packages

Tags: java, security

I am incorporating restriction rules in web application based on licensing model. I would like to update java security policy at runtime with information present in license file. This can be access to certain jars packaged inside war file or restrict access to java package.

How to dynamically restrict access to jar or package within application? Can policy file have relative or package paths?

I am looking at following sample code:

```
/**
 *  policy
 * grant {
 *    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "my.user.pwd", "read";
 *    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
 *    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
 *    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "usePolicy";
 *  };
 * 
 */

class PasswordSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("my.user.pwd", "mysecret");
            // set the policy file as the system security policy
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/C:/temp/policy/java-2.policy");
            System.setSecurityManager(new PasswordSecurityManager("mysecret"));

        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.out.println("SecurityManager already set!");
        }
        try {
            System.setProperty("my.user.pwd", "mysecret");
            DataInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\TEMP\\policy\\test.txt"));
            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\TEMP\\policy\\outputtext.txt"));
            String inputString;
            while ((inputString = fis.readLine()) != null) {
                fos.writeBytes(inputString);
                fos.writeByte('\n');
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("I/O failed for SecurityManagerTest.");
        }
    }

    String password;

    PasswordSecurityManager(String password) {
        super();
        this.password = password;
    }

    private boolean accessOK() {
        System.out.println("Reading from System... the secret password?");
        String response = System.getProperty("my.user.pwd");
        if (response.equals(password))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(FileDescriptor filedescriptor) {
        if (!accessOK())
            throw new SecurityException("Not a Chance!");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String filename) {
        if (!accessOK())
            throw new SecurityException("No Way!");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRead(String filename, Object executionContext) {
        if (!accessOK())
            throw new SecurityException("Forget It!");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(FileDescriptor filedescriptor) {
        if (!accessOK())
            throw new SecurityException("Not!");
    }

    @Override
    public void checkWrite(String filename) {
        if (!accessOK())
            throw new SecurityException("Not Even!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following method on above code solves my problem....

```
    @Override
public void checkPackageAccess(String pkg) {
    super.checkPackageAccess(pkg);
    System.out.println("checkPackageAccess.." + pkg);
    if (!accessOK()) {
        if (pkg.startsWith("my.specialpackage.path")) {
            throw new SecurityException("No access to " + pkg);
        }
    }
}
```